# Using java8 streams to prevent duplicate code

Tags: java, java-8, duplicates, java-stream

I have this object List
and

```
class ResultDto {
  private Integer field1;
  private Integer field2;
  ...etc
}
```

I whould like to create 2 objects of ResultDto. The first one contains the max of all the field1 in List and the second one contains an average of all the field1 in List.
Same thing for field2.

```
List<ResultDto>                          ResultDto
resultDto1      resultDto2          =>   resultDto
field1          field1              =>   field1=max(field1, field2)
field2          field2              =>   field2=average(field1,field2)
```

I have many fields in ResultDto (35).

What is the best way to do this ? in streams or old fashion java
right now i do something like this :

```
for (GetResultDto result : resultDtoList){

        moyValues.setMeanSpeed(moyValues.getMeanSpeed() != null ? moyValues.getMeanSpeed() + result.getMeanSpeed(): result.getMeanSpeed()) ;
        if(minValues.getMeanSpeed() == null) {minValues.setMeanSpeed(result.getMeanSpeed());}
        if(result.getMeanSpeed() > minValues.getMeanSpeed()) {minValues.setMeanSpeed(result.getMeanSpeed());}
        if(maxValues.getMeanSpeed() == null) {maxValues.setMeanSpeed(result.getMeanSpeed());}
        if(result.getMeanSpeed() > maxValues.getMeanSpeed()) {maxValues.setMeanSpeed(result.getMeanSpeed());}

        moyValues.setMaxSpeed(moyValues.getMaxSpeed() != null ? moyValues.getMaxSpeed() + result.getMaxSpeed() : result.getMaxSpeed()) ;
        if(minValues.getMaxSpeed() == null) {minValues.setMaxSpeed(result.getMaxSpeed());}
        if(result.getMaxSpeed() < minValues.getMaxSpeed()) {minValues.setMaxSpeed(result.getMaxSpeed());}
        if(maxValues.getMaxSpeed() == null) {maxValues.setMaxSpeed(result.getMaxSpeed());}
        if(result.getMaxSpeed() > maxValues.getMaxSpeed()) {maxValues.setMaxSpeed(result.getMaxSpeed());}
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: How would streams help here? You'd make your code a lot clearer by extracting some methods that handle the logic. Using ternary operators just makes it look horrible.

Comment: In stream, with IntSummaryStatistics

Comment: Do you really have 35 separate Integer fields? Why you're not using an array of Integers as a single field?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
private static final List<ResultDto> results = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new ResultDto(1, 2),
        new ResultDto(3, 4)
));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResultDto resultDto1 = toResultDto(
            results.stream().collect(summarizingInt(dto -> dto.filed1)));
    ResultDto resultDto2 = toResultDto(
            results.stream().collect(summarizingInt(dto -> dto.filed2)));
}

private static ResultDto toResultDto(IntSummaryStatistics statistics) {
    return new ResultDto(statistics.getMax(), (int) statistics.getAverage());
}
```

Comment: this way, i'll have to loop over the list as many time as the number of fields that i have. Is this right ? or does the steam make a cache of the list ?
Also, should i use parallelStream so that i can have better performance ?
Thank you

Comment: @batmaniac If you don't want to loop over the list many times, you should create your own collector (there are many questions here in SO about that)

Answer (score 1):

You need a few property access lambdas, something like

```
update(results, moyValues, minValues, maxValues, 
                v -> v.getMeanSpeed(), (v, x) -> v.setMeanSpeed(x));
```

Using these lambdas, you should be able to replace all the get and set calls.